# Issue with Passenger + Flask on DreamHost Shared Hosting

Tags: python, flask, passenger, dreamhost

I am trying to set up Passenger for Flask on DreamHost, but this shows up in place of the FLask route when I go to my site:

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.
> We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly.

My passenger_wsgi.py file looks like this:

```
import sys, os
INTERP = os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], 'venv', 'bin', 'python')
if sys.executable != INTERP:
    os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
from flask import Flask
application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello world!'
```

When I run `python3 passenger_wsgi.py` in the command line, I get no errors, so I am not sure what to do from here. I cannot access the Passenger error log as I am using shared hosting. What should be my next steps to try to find out what is causing the problem?